# .NET open source Security Token Service for Enterprise Applications

Tags: c#, security, identity, ws-security, claims-based-identity

Currently I am researching into open source .NET Security Token Services available for enterprise scale applications. 
I require an security token service that can allow for claims based identities to be created from both a custom SQL data source and a ADFS respository.
I must have STS that support WS-Security standards 1.0 and 1.1. 
I have looked at a few options and thus far Thinktecture Identity Server II is a very good option.

Would anyone be able to suggest any alternatives available for open source .NET security token services? I prefer source code in C#.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_